# Subtype relation of Option type

Tags: scala, type-theory, subtyping

I recently learned a bit about scala's subtype system, and I got curious about `Option` type and its subtypes' relationship. I learned that following statement is true.

> if A <: B, then (A => C) >: (B => C)

Also, I understood that `A <: B` means that there exists some instance of `B` that cannot be an instance of `A`. If I apply these to `Option` type, then I get following results. I'll skip `ⱯA.` notation for convenience.

1. `Nothing` <: `Option[A]`, so `Option[A] => string` <: `Nothing => string`
2. I cannot think of any instance of `Nothing => string` that is not an instance of `Option[A] => string`, so `Nothing => string` <: `Option[A] => string`
3. `Nothing => string` (<: and >:) `Option[A] => string`, so `Nothing => string` is effectively equal to `Option[A] => string` in subtyping
4. `Option[A] => string` <: `Some[A] => string`, so `Nothing => string` <: `Some[A] => string`
5. `Some[A]` <: `Nothing`

Since I strongly doubt the result is correct, I think something went wrong in the middle. Can anybody explain what's happening here?

Comment: I think the problem is step 2. What do you expect instances of `Nothing[A] -> string` to do (in general) with an input of type `Something[A]`?

Comment: @myrtlecat Since `Nothing[A]` doesn't contain any information about `A` in it, I think all functions of type `Nothing[A] -> string` will return constant string (if it is pure function of course). So, I thought it will just return constant string just as before event if argument is of type `Something[A]`.

Comment: (1.) `(A -> C) >: (B -> C)` what types are those supposed to be? Do you mean functions, so `(A => C) >: (B => C)`. (2.) `Nothing` does not have a type parameter, so `Nothing[A]` does not exist. Do you mean [`None`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/None$.html) which is a sub-type of `Option[Nothing]`? Perhaps give a reference/link to the statement you quote.

Comment: `Nothing` does not take any type parameters.

Comment: @0__ I have haskell background, so maybe I confused some notations between haskell and scala. Sorry for that. For 1, I meant function types. For 2, I didn't know `Nothing` doesn't have type parameter, and thank you for noticing that. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing up some things. I take it that `A -> B` should mean `A => B`, a function from `A` to `B`. Next, `Nothing[A]` doesn't exist, only `Nothing` which is a bottom type in Scala (sub-type of all types). But probably you mean the object `None` (with type `None.type`) which is a sub-type of `Option`.

Then your first assumption would be true:

```
implicitly[None.type <:< Option[_]]   // ok
implicitly[(Option[_] => String) <:< (None.type => String)]  // ok
```

I rephrase your second assumption:

> I cannot think of any instance of `None.type => String` that is not an instance of `Option[A] => String`, so `(None.type => String) <: (Option[A] => String)`

This assumption is wrong:

```
implicitly[(None.type => String) <:< (Option[_] => String)]
```

> ```
> error: Cannot prove that None.type => String <:< Option[_] => String.
>        implicitly[(None.type => String) <:< (Option[_] => String)]
>                  ^
> ```

It might be difficult to imagine, because `None` does not *add any methods that are not part of the interface of* `Option`. But take the typical example of general animal (as `Option`) and particular animal (as `None`).

```
trait Animal  // aka Option
object Dog extends Animal { def bark() = "bark!" }
object Cat extends Animal { def purr() = "purr!" } // aka None
```

Your second assumption would mean that `(Cat => String) <: (Animal => String)`. If this *was true*, the following would be possible:

```
val fun: Animal => String = { c: Cat.type => c.purr }  // doesn't compile
```

let's force that:

```
val fun: Animal => String = { c: Cat.type => c.purr } .asInstanceOf[Animal => String]
fun(Dog)  // try run this
```

> ```
> java.lang.ClassCastException: Dog$ cannot be cast to Cat$
>   ... 64 elided
> ```

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, but I actually meant `Nothing` type for here. I edited question for that.

Comment: @Yang ok, but it changes nothing (no pun intended). The same relations hold if you change `None.type` for `Nothing` here.

Comment: I thought there would be no error since `purr` is just a function returning constant string! So if I understand correctly, is content of the function independent of type relationships?

Comment: Well `purr` is only defined in the sub-type, so if you assume the input type of the function is _more general_, that would mean you could pass in an object of a type (`Animal` or `Dog`) that does _not define_ that method, so it can't be correct, as the implemention might rely on the refined interface. Also imagine `case class Cat(name: String)`, then you'd be able to call `name` and that's not necessary a constant string. The compiler / type-system doesn't know anything about right-hand-side implementation issues, it only cares about the types for correctness.

Answer (score 0):

I'll simply take apart every step.

1. `Nothing` does not take any type parameters. You probably meant `None`, which is of type `None.type`, which in turn is an `Option[Nothing]`.
2. Why not?

-

```
def foo(n: None.type): String = "blah"
println(foo(None)) // ok
// println(foo(Some("string"))) // doesn't compile.
```

1. False.
2. Transitivity in principle correct, but previous step wrong
3. False, because previous steps wrong. Why this reasoning should hold in general is not entirely clear.

So, no. Now you can think of a function that takes `None` but not a general `Option`.

Note: `None.type` is the type of the singleton object `None`. In general, the type of singleton object `Obj` is `Obj.type`.